# Redis user group table design

Tags: redis

I need to maintain a list of users in a group.

Right now, I'm using this to add users to the group:

```
SADD g:group1 u:bob -- Join group1
```

then this to get the list back:

```
SMEMBERS g:group1 -- List users in group1
```

But, I'm not sure how to remove users when they leave the group.  (There doesn't seem to be a `SDEL` command.)

I like the idea of using this instead:

```
SETEX g:group1:bob 60 1 -- Join group1 (auto-logout in 60s)
KEYS g:group1:* -- List users in group1
```

But, I don't think that would be the most efficient way to do it.  I think I could also accomplish this using an LPUSH/RPUSH.

What's the best way to set this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `SREM`

As an example, you can do :

```
SREM g:group1 u:bob
```

http://redis.io/commands/srem

Comment: Aha, I don't know how I missed that.  Thanks!